# Animating on a single artboard in InVision Studio?

Tags: interface-design, animation, interaction, animate, invision-studio

I'm creating a vertical scrolling interactive wizard and currently have 12+ huge 1440x6519 artboards in InVision Studio for this one project. I only need one artboard really, but with each Next button/progression I have layers coming in and out and it seems the only way InVision Studio can animate is by going from artboard to artboard.

Also I know Studio (beta) is having some issues with being a bit laggy right now, but with all these artboards it's really crawling and I'm hoping to solve this with one artboard where someone could click elements within, and progress through the animation.

Hopefully I'm wrong and you can animate within an artboard with a click of a layer, but haven't been able to find anything. In the end I'd love to create something like this.

[image]

Is this possible within InVision Studio using one artboard, or is there a way to do this an easier way?

Comment: Have you looked at this article? https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002079991-Prototyping-with-Advanced-Animations

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that could not happen. The algorithm and the technique they are using to handle the motions and timeline is all based on the differences on start and finishing point of each object.

For example :

I have a 40px X 40px Square and if I wanted to make it a circle with animation, all I have to do is draw a square on the first artboard and a circle on the other one. The Software would compare these two objects (because of their same name) and will modify the object on the first artboard to match with the second one.